# Call function if argument not null in C#

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, nullable

With enabled nullable context in C# project, I want to create some extension method that takes a value, and if it is not null, calls the function with this argument. If argument is null, the null is returned. It's almost like non-coalescing ?. operator, but called on an arbitrary function rather than a method. And I want it to be working on both val and ref types. I tried a function

```cs
public static TRes? CallOrNull<TArg, TRes>(this TArg? arg, Func<TArg, TRes> func)  
   where TArg : notnull
        => arg switch
       {
          null => default,
          { } argObj => func(argObj),
        };
```

on the following

```cs
int Add5(int i) => i + 5;

var expectedNull = ((int?) null).CallOrNull(Add5);
var expected_10  = ((int?) 5).CallOrNull(Add5);
```

This does not compile, though with an error `Expected a method with 'Add5(int?)' signature`.
Specifying template arguments explicitly like in

```cs
_ = ((int?) null).CallOrNull<int, int>(Add5);
```

does not help either. The same if I comment template specification, `//where TArg : notnull`.

Any ideas?

Comment: if `Add5` was an extension method, you could just use `?.Add5()` - worth investigating?

Comment: the error I see is "CS0411 The type arguments for method 'P.CallOrNull<TArg, TRes>(TArg?, Func<TArg, TRes>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." - which seems to make sense; the method resolution is fighting the overload resolution

Comment: this seem a bit like what is done in C# functional extensions' MayBe-class. have you looked into this library? It might fit your needs. https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/blob/master/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/Maybe/MaybeExtensions.cs

Comment: What is the reason that `CallOrNull` does not work? Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: I get a different error than the one you say happens - I get the same one as Marc sees.

Comment: @MarcGravell, when I've added argument types explicitly, it did not compile either.
I wonder why, looks to me like a compiler bug.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, you are right, the message in my post is from Resharper's popup comment, but it's more concise and comprehensive than the one from compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it working finally. Just created 2 overload for `class` and `struct` generic constraints:

```
public static TRes? CallOrNull<TArg, TRes>(this TArg? arg, Func<TArg, TRes> func)
    where TArg : struct
    => arg switch
    {
        null => default,
        { } argObj => func(argObj),
    };

public static TRes? CallOrNull<TArg, TRes>(this TArg? arg, Func<TArg, TRes> func)
    where TArg : class
    => arg switch
    {
        null => default,
        { } argObj => func(argObj),
    };
```

Good that it's working, still don't get why the original version did not.